# Using Python struct.unpack with 1-byte variables

Tags: python, binary, parsing

How can I use `struct.unpack()` or some other function available in Python to easily convert *one* byte variable to a Python integer? Right now, it is done in a rather lame way:

```
file = open("telemetry.dat", "rb").read()
magic = file[0]
int(binascii.hexlify(magic), 16)
```

Is there another?

Comment: No need for hexlify with `str.encode('hex')`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

how about `ord(my_byte)` ?

Or if the variable content is like `my_byte == "0xff"` or `ff`
you can simply do `int(my_byte, 16)`

If you have a streamof hex digits, you can do:

```
int_bytes = (int(my_bytes[i:i+2], 16) for i in xrange(0, len(my_bytes), 2) )
```

Comment: It requires a one-character string. How can I apply it to, say, 0xff?

Comment: Ah, David - -better provide this example on the question itself

Comment: No, it's binary data read from a file. I'll update and improve my question now.

Comment: `int()` can handle a '0x' prefix on its own; no need to involve slicing.

Comment: my_byte isn't a string containing "0xff". It is a byte containing this exact value, like a C char. It can as well be an unprintable character.

Comment: David: so, my first answer is the correct one. The fact that the byte is printede as "\xff"  does not mean it's content spams for four bytes - it is just python way of representing the value 0xff within a string.  
You want the numerical value for the a byte inside a  lenght-1 string: the python built-in that gives you this value is "ord" as stated.

Comment: [Cross-posting the comment from the reply abvove] I think that ord() will also work fine; however, when I need to parse a sequence of one-byte variables unpack() is slightly more convenient, since it can be used like a, b, c = unpack("3B", file[0:3]).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [struct.unpack()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) with 1-Byte variables; see the example below:

```
import struct
my_byte = b'\x07';
my_int = struct.unpack('>H', b'\x00' + my_byte)[0]

print type(my_int)
print my_int
```

The above example assumes your int is an unsigned int. Take a look at the [Format Characters section of the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters) if you need something different (e.g. a signed int, which would be '>h' for the 'fmt' parameter of the unpack function call).

Comment: You don't need `"H"` to get Python integer: `ord(my_byte) == struct.unpack("B", my_byte)[0] == my_int == 0x07`

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way to interpret each byte from a file as an integer is to use `array` module:

```
import os
from array import array

a = array("B") # interpret each byte as unsigned integer [0, 255]
with open("telemetry.dat", "rb") as file:
    a.fromfile(file, os.path.getsize(file.name))
```

If you already have data as a bytestring; you could use `bytearray` or `memoryview` (the latter behaves differently on different Python versions):

```
data = b"\xff\x64d"
# a.fromstring(data)
b = bytearray(data)
print(b[0]) # -> 255
```

Here's the corresponding `struct.unpack()` analog (more generic) that returns a tuple:

```
import struct

data = b"\xff\x64d"
t = struct.unpack(len(data)*"B", data)
print(t[-1]) # -> 100
```

For a single byte represented as a bytestring, you could use `ord()` [suggested by @jsbueno](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2051076/4279):

```
i = ord(b"d") # -> 100
```

Answer (score -7):

Are you asking about `struct.unpack( 'b', someByte )`?

A "byte" is a 1-character string.

The value `0xff` is an integer, and already unpacked.

If you're finding the 4-character value `0xff` in an input file, you're best served by `eval()` since your input file contains Python code, `0xff`.

Comment: `eval()`? Seriously? Not `int(s, 16)`?

Comment: Yes, struct.unpack('b', someByte) (or, rather, "B") appears to be what I've been looking for. Must have overlooked it in the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: @David: are you REALLY sure ord(file[0]) would give different result?

Comment: Depends on `unpack('b',` vs. `unpack('B',`.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams:  Yes.  Seriously.  I don't really think any sociopaths are going sneak evil code into the input file and replace `0xff` with `import subprocess; subprocess.Popen('format C:')`.  I'm really, really sure nothing bad will happen from using `eval()` like this.

Comment: Interesting that you can be "really, really sure nothing bad will happen" when you're answering a question, from a "random" developer, with limited context into the problem domain.  What if this code ends up publicly released and used/misused in other contexts?  Or ends up getting migrated to a web service, etc, etc.

Comment: The sociopath -- the one who is so evil that they would attempt to doctor those four bytes of a file -- has the entire Python source code for the application completely available to them. Why mess around with 4 silly bytes of some file, which the sociopath can create real havoc by simply fixing the code to raise havoc.

Comment: Another assumption that's not necessarily true.  Python as a web service, for example, does not provide for the "there are so many easier ways to do malicious things, being careless here won't matter" construct.  Also, there's no requirement for a sociopath, bad things can also happen on accident.  Why use a questionable practice that may lead to a problem when there are other practices that cannot?

Comment: @Travis Bradshow: Of all the possible permutations of 4 characters, none include anything remotely dangerous; no python statement (except) `def` is short enough.  The odds of an "accident" are zero; unless you allow for a sociopath to maliciously edit the file.  No, there are *real* security concerns like compromised passwords, bad handling of user authentication credentials and Windows that are far more important than `eval`.

Comment: @Antony: I think that ord() will also work fine; however, when I need to parse a sequence of one-byte variables unpack() is slightly more convenient, since it can be used like a, b, c = unpack("3B", file[0:3]).

Comment: @S.Lott: I think I'll avoid using eval(). Although these data files we need to parse are automatically generated, they're still supplied to us by a third party.